# Send custom response from validator in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a register user route which takes `name` , `email` and `password`. It works perfectly fine if the data is correct i.e. unique email and params are present, but if the user is already registered then Laravel sends auto error message in its own format. I want return format to be consistent in case of success or failure.

Successful Register return data:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjUsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly8xMjcuMC4wLjE6ODAwMC9hcGkvYXV0aC9yZWdpc3RlciIsImlhdCI6MTUyMTI3NTc5MiwiZXhwIjoxNTIxMjc5MzkyLCJuYmYiOjE1MjEyNzU3OTIsImp0aSI6Ik1wSzJSYmZYU1dobU5UR0gifQ.fdajaDooBTwP-GRlFmAu1gtC7_3U4ygD1TSBIqdPHf0"
}
```

But in case of error it sends data in other format.

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"email":["The email has already been taken."]}}
```

I want both of them to be consistent. Success return data is fine. But i want to customize data if failure occurs. Something like this:

```
{"status":"error","message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"email":["The email has already been taken."]}}
```

Basically, I need `status` param to be coming with every response.

Also, I had one query while using Postman the output was pure HTML when error occurred the HTML page was default Laravel Page on the other hand when angular sends the same request the error is json format which i just pasted above.
Since angular is getting JSON respose in any case it is fine for me. But why didn't postman showed me that response.

Register Controller:

```
public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
    {
        $newUser = $this->user->create([
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->get('password'))
        ]);
        if (!$newUser) {
            return response()->json(['status'=>'error','message'=>'failed_to_create_new_user'], 500);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'token' => $this->jwtauth->fromUser($newUser)
        ]);
    }
```

Register Request Handler:

```
 public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required | email | unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you always get the error-response without the 'status' key.

What happens with your current code, are a couple of things:

- RegisterController@register(RegisterRequest $request) is called by a route
- Laravel sees you use the RegisterRequest class as an argument, and will instantiate this class for you.
- Instantiating this class means it will directly validates the rules.
- If the rules are not met, laravel directly responds with the errors found.
- This response will always be in laravel's default 'layout' and the code stops there.

Conclusion: Your code is not even triggered when your validation rules are not met.

I've looked into a solution and came up with this:

```
public function register(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    //Define your validation rules here.
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required | email | unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];
    //Create a validator, unlike $this->validate(), this does not automatically redirect on failure, leaving the final control to you :)
    $validated = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

    //Check if the validation failed, return your custom formatted code here.
    if($validated->fails())
    {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'messages' => 'The given data was invalid.', 'errors' => $validated->errors()]);
    }

    //If not failed, the code will reach here
    $newUser = $this->user->create([
        'name' => $request->get('name'),
        'email' => $request->get('email'),
        'password' => bcrypt($request->get('password'))
    ]);
    //This would be your own error response, not linked to validation
    if (!$newUser) {
        return response()->json(['status'=>'error','message'=>'failed_to_create_new_user'], 500);
    }

    //All went well
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'token' => $this->jwtauth->fromUser($newUser)
    ]);
}
```

Now, not conforming your validation rules still triggers an error, but your error, and not laravel's built-in error :)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 8 I added my custom invalidJson with the "success": false:

in app/Exceptions/Handler.php:

```
/**
 * Convert a validation exception into a JSON response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
protected function invalidJson($request, ValidationException $exception)
{
    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        'errors' => $exception->errors(),
    ], $exception->status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i came up with:

```
function validate(array $rules)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), $rules);
    $errors = (new \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException($validator))->errors();
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        throw new \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException(response()->json(
            [
                'status'     => false,
                'message'    => "Some fields are missing!",
                'error_code' => 1,
                'errors'     => $errors,
            ], \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY));
    }
}
```

Create a helper directory (`App\Helpers`) and add it into a file. don't forget to add that into your composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/system.php",
    ],
},
```

Now you can call `validate()` in your controllers and get what you want:

```
validate([
    'email'    => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required|min:6|max:32',
    'remember' => 'nullable|boolean',
    'captcha'  => 'prod_required|hcaptcha',
]);
```